Structuring Data for Bidirectional BLE Communication between MCU and Mobile App
I am currently sending data from STM32 to a mobile app using BLE. I use a specific characteristic for the data, which starts with a header containing a CMD. This CMD indicates the type of data being sent. I have only three commands so far. Now, I am unsure about the best practices for sending data back from the app to the STM32:

Should I use the same characteristic for both directions, or should I use a different one?
For the CMD in the header, should I create a new set of commands, or can they share the same enum list? For now I have the same list:

typedef enum {
    BLE_P_TYPE_NONE = 0x00,

    // STM32 -> PC
    BLE_P_TYPE_GW_INFO = 0x01,
    BLE_P_TYPE_NODES_INFO = 0x02,

    // PC -> STM32
    BLE_P_TYPE_START_PAIR = 0x80,
    BLE_P_TYPE_STOP_PAIR = 0x81,
    BLE_P_TYPE_DELETE_NODE = 0x82,
    BLE_P_TYPE_NODE_CONTROL = 0x83,

} eBLELinkCharPacketType;

Thank you for your advice!

For the first question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159968/556495.

Can you please clarify the second question? What will the new set of commands be used for?

@YoussifSaeed I edited main post: Should I always start commands from zero, or share the same table for both directions?

For the second question, it's completely up to you. If you at any point would like to simultaneously additionally support the protocol in the reverse direction, you should use one set for both directions, e.g. like the Attribute Protocol in BLE.
